# Beginner MYSQL Error - Access Denied

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1045

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: N
O)

I've tried EVERYTHING, I've read through pages of answers and no-one seems to know the right one.

When i try to log into my DB i just get the above error, I havent set a password or anything.

Can't log into MySQL at all now, don't understand.

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain how you're trying to log into the database.

Are you trying to log into the command line client or access it from a program? Also, what command/code are you using to do this?

Comment: Hi Chris, I'm using mysql -u root -p

When it prompts for the password I'm just pressing enter

It worked fine, then just stopped working fine.

Comment: Since you've not set a root password, have you tried <code>mysql -u root</code>? Although why mysql would complain about the redundant -p option I don't know...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the `-p` option. (Tells mysql that you want to provide a password when logging in.)

```
$ mysql -u root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
```

---

If that doesn't work, try [B.5.4.1. How to Reset the Root Password](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html) from the MySQL Reference Manual.

Comment: Thanks mate, I'm using:

mysql -u root -p

No password set - just pressing enter but still not working.

Comment: Try http://www.netadmintools.com/art90.html (including the section starting with "To reset a root password that you forgot") or http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html worked perfectly for me.

Thanks alot mate.

Comment: aioobe, incorporate the comment into your answer so I can upvote it :)

Comment: @chrisbunney, sure, that's actually a good idea. I will remember it for future comments too.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ mysql -u root -p{you_password} {db_name}
```

just remove '{}' from the string.

Comment: Not recommended as the password will be stored in clear text in the bash-history file.

Comment: @aioobe Yes, but on testing/debug period it's the easiest one... In my opinion, the best way, is to create my.cnf in the users dir, with password field inside... But, it's not a noob way as you can see :)

Answer (score 0):

In the services.msc check if mysql is running as local system or network system. By default, it should be network system , change that to local system and restart the service.

Comment: Switching the account to Local System is discouraged and is actually a bad advice.