# access is denied for user 'root'@localhost mysql error 1045

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1045

I am new to PHP. I get the following error when executing my application:

In phpMyadmin the code is like this

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPasswordRoot'] = true;
```

As I have taken back up, I have change the above code to

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'Pass123';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPasswordRoot'] = true;
```

Now I am get the following error

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)  MySQL Error # :1045

Please let me know, what went wrong here.

Comment: Have you confirmed whether 1) you have the correct username/password? 2) Whether your domain can actually connect to the mysql server (use phpMyAdmin to verify this)

Comment: Have you done a little searching, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912761/beginner-mysql-error-access-denied http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540794/unable-to-access-mysql-from-myphpadmin-after-setting-root-password-in-easyphpwam http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532868/mysql-error-1045-access-denied

Comment: share some code.... so we can help, seems that you are not passing the right pasword to the function  mysql_connect

Comment: [Search stackoverflow with google](http://www.google.com/search?q=access+is+denied+for+user+'root'%40localhost+mysql+error+1045&sitesearch=stackoverflow.com/questions&qscrl=1)

Comment: It was working fine.. If enter wrong password then it was showing Error message as "Incorrect password". but now its directly showing error page....

Comment: @JohnP: "access denied" means it can connect, but couldn't log in. If it was a connection issue, it'd be "connection refused"

Answer (score 3):

After wasting most of a day on this problem, it turned out that all i had to do was supply the non-localhost hostname. I've no idea why (the user is allowed to connect from Any host), but it works!

```
root@base:~# mysql -u username -h hostname -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
```

And in PHP:

```
Test 1807:
<?php
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$hostname = "actualhostnamenotlocalhost"; 

$con = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

mysqli_close($con);    

?>
OK.
```

Answer (score 2):

Nobody here has mentioned that (for some reason or another), the host assigned to your user might be wrong. When it says `root@localhost` it means the user `root` with the host of `localhost`.

On some servers, the default `root` might not be on `localhost`. Try these:

`root@127.0.0.1`

`root@[yourhostname]`

Answer (score 0):

Please check the password which you typed here.

These kind of errors come when youre password is not matching with the original password.

Comment: how can i reset the password now

Answer (score 0):

make sure whether you've assigned a password for mysql

Comment: no i haven't assign any password to it... I did as i have mentioned above only

Comment: then do not assign password here `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'Pass123'` remove the 'pass123'

Answer (score 0):

For resetting youre password 
please look into this page http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Answer (score 0):

There can be a problem with MySQL-server and the port on which it is run. Default is 3306. If it doesn't work, change the port in the `my.ini` (ór whatever the mysql-ini filename is) AND also change the port-reference in the `config.inc.php` in the phpmyadmin-folder.

So, the error that is explained here (by Gnanendra)

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) MySQL Error # :1045

may be given because MySQL-server is not run correctly.

Also check this post for more information on this issue:

[Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: No such file or directory](http://www.danielschneller.com/2007/10/cant-start-server-bind-on-tcpip-port-no.html)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the password correct (caps lock?) and perhaps use the raw IP address i.e. 127.0.0.1