# MySQL Access denied error

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I am trying to install mySQL on a Mac OS 10.8 and set up a user account. 
NOTE I am a abs beginner when it comes to using the command line in Terminal window.

I used these instructions to install:
http://www.macminivault.com/mysql-mountain-lion/

I set my own password for all users here:

```
 GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass' WITH GRANT OPTION;
quit
```

Every time i try to execute mySQL as a root user on the command line i get this:

```
Ciarans-MacBook-Pro:~ callanmooneys$ mysql -u root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I read around on the net and tried various things  including tried this to change password:

```
mysqladmin -u root -pyourcurrentmysqlrootpassword password yournewmysqlrootpassword,
it returns -> 
    -> USE mysql
    ->
```

If i simply type 'mysql' and launch the mySQL monitor then try to crete a user account:

```
mysql> USE mysql
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mysql'
mysql>
```

Also tried answers on forum: [access is denied for user 'root'@localhost mysql error 1045](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547288/access-is-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-mysql-error-1045?rq=1) returned 'root@127.0.0.1 command not found

And [MySQL - ERROR 1045 - Access denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489119/mysql-error-1045-access-denied?rq=1):

```
Ciarans-MacBook-Pro:~ callanmooneys$ mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
131105 21:44:41 mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/mysql/data/Ciarans-MacBook-Pro.local.err'.
131105 21:44:41 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/data
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: line 129: /usr/local/mysql/data/Ciarans-MacBook-Pro.local.err: Permission denied
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: line 166: /usr/local/mysql/data/Ciarans-MacBook-Pro.local.err: Permission denied
131105 21:44:41 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql/data/Ciarans-MacBook-Pro.local.pid ended
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: line 129: /usr/local/mysql/data/Ciarans-MacBook-Pro.local.err: Permission denied
Ciarans-MacBook-Pro:~ callanmooneys$ mysql -u root
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
Ciarans-MacBook-Pro:~ callanmooneys$
```

Feedback appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit confusing but deleted mySQL and all associated  files , re installed, set root password, logged on as 
mysql -u root -p (password)
And it worked fine.

There is allot of resources on the net which can be confusing, for anyone experiencing similar problems i recommend using the official site here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/access-denied.html